# Excel Formula: Sumifs with multiple criteria; one criteria as a range

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm having some issues getting a formula to work on my spreadsheet.  I'm using a sumifs statement to sum the FTEs (full time equivalents / staffing) for forecasting.

Specifically, I'm forecasting staffing on a weekly basis, and wish to sum depending on three criteria.  The formula sums the staffing for a particular week; which is the information in A6.

1. Is the data enabled true or false; if True, include in sum
2. Is the project type matching the correct project bucket we are looking at
3. Is the project phase/completion below a specified value

The first two criteria are single values, and absolute.  The last criteria is a range.  Basically projects are split into two phases; and since the sheet is stepping through time, I need to sum (for tha

The formula is below:

```
=SUMIFS(XLOOKUP($A6,'Data - FTE Calcs - Month'!$KA$15:$OB$15,'Data - FTE Calcs - Month'!$KA$16:$OB$115,,0), Data_FTE_Calcs_Month[Display Graph],TRUE,Data_FTE_Calcs_Month[Project Cross Reference Used],"PDB - Role A",XLOOKUP($A6,'Data - FTE Calcs - Month'!$BS$15:$FT$15,'Data - FTE Calcs - Month'!$BS$16:$FT$115,,0),Data_FTE_Calcs_Month[Phase Transition Value])
```

In a general sense, the formula symbolically is below
=SUMIFS(XLOOKUP(Specified Date, Date Range (for position), Data Matrix (for position),,0),Display Graph Range, TRUE, Project Type,"PDB - Role A", XLOOKUP(Specified Date, Date Range (Project Month/Completion) , Date Matrix (Project Month/Completion),,0),Data_FTE_Calcs_Month[Phase Transition Value])

The formula works when I replace the Data_FTE_Calcs_Month[Phase Transition Value]) with a specified value.  However, in the third criteria I want to compare the returned range; which is the month value, to the specified transition period, which is also a range/array.  This is because I'm comparing the values on a project level; and thus need to ensure I count projects where the value is less than or greater than the phase transition.

Edit 1:
I have added a few images to help highlight what I'm trying to accomplish.

The first shows that I'm essentially trying to consolidate 8 tabs of repeated data into a single tab, where the only variation is a logic check of 1 or 0 for the calculation.  The sumifs is trying to bypass this by adding only data based on a few parameters.  The calculations work currently, but the file size is rather big (50 Mb) and takes awhile to open.
[Tab Summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bipeO.png)

The second is the shot from the page showing the columns I'm working on and what data format looks like.  I've hidden the columns for the time step (104 weeks for 2 year outlook).
[Data Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poQou.png)

The third shows the compare column that I'm having issues with.  I want to compare the progress month with the defined progress column and then sum if it is less than for phase 1, and sum if it is greater than for phase 2.  Eventually I will transition this over to a % complete of the job rather than a defined month to adjust the project durations dynamically.
[Compare Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Wb1F.png)

The last image is the location where the sumifs statement lives, on a summary sheet.  This is the sheet used to build the multiple graphs desired for forecasting and 'pretty pictures'.
[Summary Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C813k.png)

Comment: Please post an image or some sample data showing the content of the various columns. It's a little difficult to tell what's going on as it is.

Comment: I have  edited the post and added images as requested.  Hopefully this makes it a bit more clear what I'm trying to do.

I'm having issues with the last portion of the sumifs statement where I compare the project month to a defined phase transition.  I want to sum the data differently (in different sections on the graph pages) for the phases.  Right now there are only two phases, and thus the transition value is known.  I either get the wrong value, or I get a vector output that isn't accurate.

Eventually I will make this a % value rather than a defined month value.

Comment: Generally, when a `sumifs` condition is an array, the result will be the first item of the array. if you wrap the sumifs with `sum` you will get the summation of the returned array.

Comment: Since is looking bit complicated therefore either share some sample data or if U r comfortable then share the WB on cloud, will help us for fix it ☺